Computer automatically wakes after suspend
My new computer, with a AMD Ryzen 5 7600 CPU and running Ubuntu 24.04, wakes up by itself immediately after I suspend. Running systemctl suspend results in the system apparently going into the suspend state (display turns black, power to external devices turns off) followed very soon after by waking up. The whole process takes a few seconds, though power to external devices (seen by a light on my wired mouse) is only off for less than 1 second.
I've found various other people asking about this same issue, and the only advice I've found for how one might determine what is waking the computer are
(a) inspect logs to find out what is waking the computer, e.g. via sudo journalctl --since="-5 minutes" or sudo dmesg -T | tail -n 200 or cat /var/log/syslog. These all seem to give the same info, which for me includes lines for the computer going into suspend mode and disabling CPUs, then immediately resuming. I see no indication of why it is waking.
smpboot: CPU 11 is now offline
kernel: ACPI: PM: Low-level resume complete
kernel: ACPI: PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
kernel: AMD-Vi: Virtual APIC enabled
kernel: AMD-Vi: Virtual APIC enabled
kernel: LVT offset 0 assigned for vector 0x400
kernel: Enabling non-boot CPUs ...

(b) disable various devices' ability to wake the computer via echo XHC0 > /proc/acpi/wakeup
I have done this and disabled every device listed in /proc/acpi/wakeup. cat /proc/acpi/wakeup | grep ena outputs nothing. Yet my computer continues to immediately wake.
(c) systemd-inhibit: Find what might be blocking suspend with systemd-inhibit --list --mode=block. When I run this I get one result, from GNOME. I was able to disable this by including InhibitorsMax=0 in /etc/systemd/logind.conf. After reboot, the list command shows no results. My computer continues to immediately wake, although now it takes slightly longer and the display doesn't come on until I move my mouse or press a key on my keyboard.
Repeating the solution from (b), disabling all devices in /proc/acpi/wakeup, again has no effect.
(d) change BIOS settings: I only see options for keyboard and mouse wakeup in my BIOS settings. Mouse is turned off. I do not want to turn keyboard off, but I did test that the computer still wakes automatically when the keyboard is disconnected.
I also tried hibernate, which seems to have just turned the computer off. Turning it back on resulted in a normal boot. EDIT: I have been able to make hibernation work now, which is nice but does not solve the issue with suspend.
Wake on LAN is disabled. sudo ethtool enp4s0 shows Wake-on: d. (Neither of the other two ethernet interfaces shown by ip a have an entry for Wake-on.) I've also suspended with my mouse unplugged, just in case, and again with my keyboard unplugged, just in case. Neither of these had any effect.
What else can I do to troubleshoot or possibly solve this problem?

Is your computer a Dell?
Not sure my comment may be of use
Last year I had a similar problem with my Dell Latitude 5530 (with win11 - unfortunately I was not allowed to use linux on it): 95% of the times I set it to sleep, it woke up after a few minutes (typically while I was commuting home, so it ended up stressed the battery). I extensively tried to debug this issue - in the end I gave up and decided to switch to hibernation (with command "rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0" )
but in the end it wakes up in only 10/15 seconds at most, and for me that is fast enough

@sigmud I don't have a UI option to hibernate, but sudo systemctl hibernate seems to just turn the computer off. This is a desktop computer I built myself.

Do you have swap? free will tell you and us.  If not, you need between 1xRAM (minimum required for suspend) and 2xRAM. Please [edit] your Question to add this information.  Do not use Add Comment.

There is "sleep", where a process voluntarily surrenders the CPU for a time. There is "suspend" where the system saves itself to RAM and enters a low power state.  There is "hibernate", where the system saves itself to disk, and turns the computer off. "Suspend" requires a modern CPU, with controllable power states. "Hibernation" requires a RAM-sized, contiguous swap space.

If the system is set to Wake-on-LAN, some errant network traffic could be causing the machine to exit from sleep.

@user68186 I have already stated in my question that I have attempted the solution given in that question. See (b) in my question: cat /proc/acpi/wakeup tells me nothing is enabled.

I never even read them, because that question is not relevant to my situation. (and those answers not relevant to that question) But since you've pointed them out, (a) snap store is not running, (b) yes, again, read my question: I tried with USB devices unplugged.

I have solved the issue. What I did is remove my swap file and create a swap partition instead. I have no idea why swap is in any way relevant to suspend, so I have no idea why this solution works.
Details:

Disable my swap file: sudo swapoff /swap.img
Remove my swap file: sudo rm /swap.img
Boot from the installation USB stick
Use Ubuntu's Disks program to shrink the main filesystem partition, making room for a swap partition
Reboot without installation USB stick
Use Ubuntu's Disks program to create a new partition
Use new partition for swap: sudo mkswap [partition's device name]
Enable swap: sudo swapon -U [swap partition's UUID]
Add this line to /etc/fstab: UUID=[swap partition's UUID]   none    swap    sw  0   0
Reboot

